# Asus laptop stuck at ROG logo screen

Tags: boot, nvidia, asus, bios, nouveau

I recently bought an Asus ROG strix G713Q and started to install Ubuntu a couple of days ago. I have made a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS live usb with Rufus and the installation went smoothly. The boot afterwards however, not so much.

The problem I have encountered is that the laptop gets stuck at **logo** screen that says "**Republic of Gamers**" no matter what I try, as can be seen in the picture. [image: as can be seen in here]

The **fast boot** is disabled,

The **secure boot** is disabled,

**No usb devices** are attached,

**Updated BIOS** to 315,

Tried to replace the "quiet splash" arguments at the linux line of GRUB Menu "Ubuntu" option with "**nomodeset**" and "**nouveau.modeset=0**" at different trials. Tried not replacing but only appending as well.

Then following the official tutorial of Asus, I tried to **reset the CMOS** and voila! I was in! I was in for a time and tried to install nvidia driver instead of this **nouveau** then gave it a restart but it did not work! I forgot to blacklist nouveau, I guess its that but I never had a second chance. Resetting CMOS -weirdly enough- never worked again.

It is truly weird that the machine works just perfect with Windows and Ubuntu Live USB. But I don't get an error message with my Ubuntu installation.

Update: Now trying to install 21.04 and got an error message at timezone selection screen as following:

`Error fsyncing/closing /dev/nvme0n1p2: Input/ouput error`

I remember seeing this error with **nvme0n1p2** before when I try to install 20.04. Not sure what it means though.

I would appreciate any suggestion.

EDIT:

I have no dual boot on installed on the machine.

Once had a Windows working smoothly but I have completely erased it to install ubuntu.

Installed Ubuntu 20.04 many times, once with a "do something else" option when formatting, but then cancelled it and reverted back to the original to do a traditional "erase everything and install ubuntu approach". All of my other formats and installs followed the latter approach as well.

- BIOS version: 315
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 5800H with Radeon Graphics 3200MHZ
- Graphics: NVIDIA RTX 3070 Laptop GPU
- Storage: Device Type NVMe, SSD (1TB), Make/Model SK Hynix HFM001TD3JX013N

Here is the output of **GParted**

[image]

Here is what comes out when I click the **info** button for red ! error icon

[image: Error icon]

Here is what **`grep -i nvme /var/log/syslog*`** prints out:

[image: SS of command]

Here is the output of the **Disks** app

[image]

Here is the output of the **NVMe smart log** (the usual smart did not work so I installed this)

[image]

Comment: What happens if you try a 21.04 Live USB and install?

Comment: haven't tried tbh. Do you think it worth a try?

Comment: Since you've already updated the BIOS... and Windows works... yes, it would be worth a try.

Comment: Is it in UEFI mode? Did you try a supervisor password in BIOS to see if any new menus come up?

Comment: @heynnema makes sense, will try.

Comment: @Raffles it is in UEFI mode but it required no password to get to advanced menus. That's how I could update the BIOS actually.

Comment: Are you dual booting with Windows? Can you boot into a live session, run GParted and take a screenshot and post it into your question?

Comment: Not a dual boot really. I could send a gparted ss yesterday but now that installed 21.04 and finally got through the logo screen, I got new problems :)

Comment: What make/model SSD? Edit your question and show me the `Disks` app **SMART Data & Tests** data window. It's a scrollable window, so it may take two screenshots to get it all. Also show me `grep -i nvme /var/log/syslog*`.

Comment: Even if I reinstall Ubuntu 20.04 to provide the information, it would not be possible to show you all that since I cant get to the terminal, I cant get it to boot successfully. GParted may have been an option since Raffles requested me to run it from Liver USB. Do you want me to use a live usb as well? I doubt that's the case.

Comment: We need to see if your hard drive has been formatted correctly and need to know if you are dual booting, overwriting Windows or something else. If you chose "Something Else" you have to know what you are doing, it's not too complicated but it must be done correctly. You can boot into a live session 20.04 or 21.04 and run both GParted and the terminal as per heynnema above which should show your current hard drive setup. You might have to format your hard drive and start from scratch and risk losing Windows, unless you back up your windows partition first.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the information, I would have never remember that if you wouldn't ask but yes, something of that sort did happen once. I added the specs and event history at the edit section of question. I am trying to provide the rest of the requested information right now.

Comment: I have added the screens from **Gparted and one of its pop-ups, Disks app, syslog, Smart Data and Tests** @heynnema.

Comment: @3yanlis1bos For the `gparted` error, you can install `dosfstools` and `mtools`. For your problem, I'd go to the ASUS and/or Hynix web sites and download their firmware updater for the SSD.

Comment: @heynnema thank you, the gparted error is gone now. But unfortunately, there is no firmware updater for the SSD at any of the locations.

Comment: @3yanlis1bos Going on a mini-vacation for 4 days. Will check back in later.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues on my Zephyrus G15, for me booting via recovery mode and then resume boot works perfectly. I have yet to try the CMOS reset though.